# Execute a bash script containing the sudo command in rootless docker

Tags: sudo, docker

I am working in a rootless docker environment and I want to execute a shell script that contains some commands with sudo, but the command sudo is not recognized in my terminal (probably because it is a rootless docker). I get the following error:

```
sudo: command not found
```

How can I execute my shell script without changing it? (I do not want to manually delete the sudo commands, in a rootless docker I just need to ignore the sudo and execute the rest of the line).

I tried to make an alias for sudo in the `.bashrc` as follows:

`alias sudo=''`,

but it is not a correct solution, because for some lines we have:

`sudo -u username ...`.

Comment: This is probably one of the reasons including `sudo` statements in a shell script is a very bad idea..

Comment: sudo is probably not installed in the container

Answer (score 1):

That may sound crazy, but I fixed the issue by just installing sudo!

`apt install sudo`

After that, the rootless docker is similar to a normal one.

Answer (score 0):

Running sudo statements on Docker is a bad idea. However, you can always try to execute the script outside docker with `docker exec -ti --user root container /path/to/script` or create a Dockerfile with you script.